# what should i do if this build error are keep repeating

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

hye, ive try to build an apk in unity but it has error. what can i do to solve this problem?

```
Win32Exception: Access is denied.

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_shell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
UnityEditor.Android.ADB.StartServer     (UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit)
UnityEditor.Android.ADB.Run (System.String[] command,     UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidDeploymentTargetsExtension.GetKnownTargets (IDeploymentTargetsMainThreadContext context, UnityEditor.ProgressHandler progressHandler)
UnityEditor.DeploymentTargets.DeploymentTargetManager.GetKnownTargets () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/DeploymentTargets/DeploymentTargetManager.cs:50)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildWindowExtension+<SpawnFetchTargetsThread>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 ()
UnityEditor.Android.<SpawnFetchTargetsThread>c__AnonStorey0:<>m__0()
```

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to check your permissions - looks like (and exception is clearly says that) your Visual Studio is prevented from starting adb server.

Comment: Just launch your IDE with admins privileges and this should solve your problem

Comment: And how do I check the permission? it is located at my pc settings.. i'm new at this

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and I solved it by re-installing the Android SDK with **cmd** run as **administrator**.

Hope it helps!